# Watson Assistant bot not extracting parameters to be send to my cloud function

Tags: webhooks

Hi so I have almost everything to make my Watson Assistant chatbot work, the only feature that is missing is send emails with user input. I made a cloud function that currently takes the parameters of email and reminder.

I am using webhooks on my chatbot for that specific skill, however when I tested it to send a reminder it doesn't take the params.reminder that I am giving it. If I test it inside the cloud function it works because I am inputting the parameters, but I don't know why is not taking it when I give it to the bot

```
 var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let smtpConfig = {
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com', // you can also use smtp.gmail.com
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use TLS
    auth: {
        user: 'myuser', 
        pass: 'mypassword'
    }
};

function main(params) {
 sendEmail(params, function (email_response) {
        });
}

function sendEmail(params, callback) {

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);
    let mailOptions = {
        from: `Watson Assistant Emails <${smtpConfig.auth.user}>`,
        to: params.email,
        subject: `REMINDER: ${params.reminder}`
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {

        let email_response = {
            code: 200,
            msg: 'Email was sent successfully',
            reason: 'Success'
        };
        return email_response;
    });
}
```

---

I am also attaching images of what my current bot is like and where I have my webhooks Thank you in advance again! [Part 1 of chatbot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csBRJ.png)  [Next dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtJhN.png) [Webhook call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFvEK.png)